# How to mock Class.forName() in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method which calls Class.forName() inside it. And when I create a unit test it throws ClassNotFoundException. Is there a way to mock Class.forName() behavior?

method need to test:

```java
public Map<String, Object> invokeOperation(String className, String methodName) {
      try {
         final Class<?> implClass =
                 Class.forName(className);
         final Object obj= implClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
         final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = getParamTypes();
         final Object[] args = getParamValues();
         final Method method = obj.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
         final Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) method.invoke(obj, args);
         return result;
      } catch (final ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: Why try to mock Class.forName() instead of simply passing a valid, exising class name in your test?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito [does not support](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1471) mocking static methods. If you really want to do it, you can look at [PowerMock](http://powermock.github.io/).

But a better way, as already mentioned, is not to mock anything at all. Just pass a real, valid class name (and its method name) to the method and test whether it works properly. I'd also be a good idea to create a class (or classes) for test purpose only, so you wouldn't need to fix the test each time a class is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should mock `Class.forName` method.

Instead consider:

1. Create a special class for test that you would like to check for in tests, put it into `src/test/java` folder if you're using a build system (like maven), so that this class won't reach the production artifact. This will cover a "happy path"
2. If you want to test for exceptions, consider the following refactoring (I'll call the class that contains `invokeOperation` method `OperationInvoker`):

```
public class OperationInvoker {
  private ClassByNameResolver classByNameResolver;
  public OperationInvoker(ClassByNameResolver classByNameResolver) {
     this.classByNameResolver = classByNameResolver;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> invokeOperation(String className, String methodName) {
      try {
         final Class<?> implClass = classByNameResolver.resolveClass(className);

         final Object obj= implClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
         final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = getParamTypes();
         final Object[] args = getParamValues();
         final Method method = obj.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
         final Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) method.invoke(obj, args);
         return result;
      } catch (final ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}

public class ClassByNameResolver { // or provide an interface and implementation
   public Class<?> resolveClass(String name) throws ... {
      return Class.forName(name);
   }
}
```

Now this allows easy mocking the `ClassByNameResolver` with mockito to simulate the 
situation where the exception will be thrown.

Its a matter of taste, but in this case the unit test can cover both of these classes together (unit = two classes)